# Could not load file or assembly 'ConsoleApplication1'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I just open a new C# project , but when i want to compile it i give the title error . i search for this error but didn't find any result .

---

what am i going to do ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you rename the project after creating it? Did you try to restart visual studio and try again?

Comment: is hello world the only thing you did to the project? Is it in a solution/project all alone? Also.. might want to add a Console.ReadLine(); after the write so it will stay open instead of just flashing.

Comment: no i dont rename it , no

Comment: Did you build the project? If you don't know, make sure by right clicking the project in the solution explorer and choose Build.

Comment: @Nico Schertler:yes i build the project first .

Comment: And did it compile without errors?  Look in the Output window.  And do you see the .exe in the bin\Debug directory of the project?  Double-click it to see what happens.

Comment: no , i give this error : the application failed to properly . Thanks Hans , its from my pc

Comment: Why do you need to use linq, collections.generic and text?

Answer (score 1):

- Try cleaning the project.
- Make sure that the startup item isn't set
  to a non-existant ConsoleApplication1.
- Whatever the main form of
  your project is, right click on it in Solution Explorer and select
  "Set as Start Up...".
- Make sure that the Program.cs (or Program.vb)
  file is not attempting to load ConsoleApplication1.

Comment: i think its a fault of my windows and i must reinstall it . Thanks Ami

Comment: @user1259236 - don't forget to replace all electrical wiring in your entire house first.